# Update bootstrap wysiHTML5 editor textarea in cursor position?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, rich-text-editor

I am using bootstrap WYSIWYG editor text area it should get updated in cursor position when ever adding data from another pop up.

I have done it by getting an old value from an editor and append it with new value to set in editor.

But its not a right since all the new values are appended in the end of old value. It should be updated where the cursor is located in editor.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: can't u use a different variable to store the 'old value' so the new value is not appended to it? or is your question is unclear.

Comment: See I have a text area and select box with some values. When user places the cursor anywhere inside the text area and select the value from dropdown it should be injected in the specfic position where the cursor placed

Comment: I have found the solution thanks

Comment: @sridhar mind posting your solution here?